# ng-bootstrap: Modal global options

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

We are using ng-bootstrap 1.0.

I need to disable the escape key, which closes the modal.

I understand that it can be done with:

```
`modalOption.keyboard = false;`
```

How can I apply this setting to all modals in my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap `NgbModal.open` in a service method, and call that method to open modals throughout your application. In the method, `keyboard: false` is appended to the other options supplied as an optional argument. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtpehz) for a demo.

**In service**:

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

public openModal(content, options = {}) {
  return this.modalService.open(content, { ...options, keyboard: false });
}
```

**In component**:

```
openMyCenteredModal(content) {
  this.myService.openModal(content, { centered: true });
}
```

Comment: Merci! I thought there would be a way like tooltip shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659477/set-global-config-of-tooltip-for-ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

have more option apply in module file that contain your modal like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      MyModalComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
      MyModalComponent,
    ]
  })
  export class AddAgentModalModule { 
    constructor(
        configModal: NgbModalConfig,
      ) {
        configModal.backdrop = 'static';
        configModal.keyboard = false;
      }    
  }
```

this will affect on all time you open your modal.